# Using RandomFileAccess to temporarly cache audio data

Tags: android

I'm currently using a simple byte array buffer to cache live audio data and than playback this data. So it's constant reads and writes on this buffer.  My problem is that I sometimes need this buffer to be atleast 1MB and I know that allocating that much memory is most likely not a good idea. So therefore I'm looking into caching data temporarily under the cache folder.

Are there any pitfalls when using RandomFileAccess to continuously seek->read and seek->write?

Are there perhaps better methods to cache temporarily data?

My main concerns are to maximize performance and battery life.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is a [MappedByteBuffer](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/nio/MappedByteBuffer.html) (in Java), or [mmap()](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mmap) (in C).

This is nicely optimized on Linux, and actually used all over the place in the Android OS.

And you can almost forget about memory limits when using such mapped files.

Comment: Ohh... This is very interesting.. :) Thanks! Let me try to see if I can understand how to use it properly.